# keep the punctuation of the sentence but remove all special characters for the irreverent information Python

Tags: python, regex

i have the text from html. currently, i want to keep the punctuation of the sentence but remove all special characters for the irreverent information(non sentence).

i try the statement:

```
 sentences = re.sub('none', '', text)
 sentences = re.sub(ur"[^\w\d'\s]+", '', sentences.strip())
 print sentences
```

text:

```
acting career of tom cruise started quite early but with a small role in the movie endless love (1981). however, he got his big break as a supporting actor in the movie taps later that year. in 1983, his movies risky business and all the right moves along with top gun in 1986 paved the path for tom cruise as an established actor and a superstar. after this there was no looking back and tom cruise went to star in many super-successful movies like cocktail, rain man, days of thunder, interview with the vampire.
then in 1996, he starred as a superspy ethan hunt in the very popular and blockbuster movie which went on to be a series, mission: impossible. that same year he also was seen in the lead role of the movie jerry maguire and won a golden globe for the same. in 1999, his supporting role in the movie magnolia again won him his second golden globe.
after repeated success in many films, tom cruise kept going on with release of two mission impossible movies, war of the worlds which was a super duper box office hit and many more.
net worth
tom cruise’s films have gained $7.3 million worldwide as of 2013. however, the net worth of the highest paid actor in hollywood is $270 million and he still gets paychecks from his previous movies.

you may also like 
the top 10 highest paid actors of all time

al pacino salary

how much money does jean-claude van damme make? (salary & net worth)

how much money does arnold schwarzenegger make? (net worth & biography)

how much money does jean-claude van damme make? (net worth)
posted in
action ,
celebs
tags:
highest paid actor ,
highest paid actor in hollywood ,
net worth ,
salary ,
thomas cruise mapother ,
tom cruise
«
```

result of sentence:

```
acting career of tom cruise started quite early but with a small role in the movie endless love 1981 however he got his big break as a supporting actor in the movie taps later that year in 1983 his movies risky business and all the right moves along with top gun in 1986 paved the path for tom cruise as an established actor and a superstar after this there was no looking back and tom cruise went to star in many supersuccessful movies like cocktail rain man days of thunder interview with the vampire
then in 1996 he starred as a superspy ethan hunt in the very popular and blockbuster movie which went on to be a series mission impossible that same year he also was seen in the lead role of the movie jerry maguire and won a golden globe for the same in 1999 his supporting role in the movie magnolia again won him his second golden globe
after repeated success in many films tom cruise kept going on with release of two mission impossible movies war of the worlds which was a super duper box office hit and many more
net worth
tom cruises films have gained 73 million worldwide as of 2013 however the net worth of the highest paid actor in hollywood is 270 million and he still gets paychecks from his previous movies

you may also like 
the top 10 highest paid actors of all time

al pacino salary

how much money does jeanclaude van damme make salary  net worth

how much money does arnold schwarzenegger make net worth  biography

how much money does jeanclaude van damme make net worth
posted in
action 
celebs
tags
highest paid actor 
highest paid actor in hollywood 
net worth 
salary 
thomas cruise mapother 
tom cruise

how much money does mike tyson make salary  net worth
how much money does jack black make salary  net worth
```

the issue was how to keep the punctuation for the sentences, but remove the special character of non-sentence.

I want to get the result such as:

```
acting career of tom cruise started quite early but with a small role in the movie endless love (1981). however, he got his big break as a supporting actor in the movie taps later that year. in 1983, his movies risky business and all the right moves along with top gun in 1986 paved the path for tom cruise as an established actor and a superstar. after this there was no looking back and tom cruise went to star in many super-successful movies like cocktail, rain man, days of thunder, interview with the vampire.
then in 1996, he starred as a superspy ethan hunt in the very popular and blockbuster movie which went on to be a series, mission: impossible. that same year he also was seen in the lead role of the movie jerry maguire and won a golden globe for the same. in 1999, his supporting role in the movie magnolia again won him his second golden globe.
after repeated success in many films, tom cruise kept going on with release of two mission impossible movies, war of the worlds which was a super duper box office hit and many more.
net worth
tom cruise’s films have gained $7.3 million worldwide as of 2013. however, the net worth of the highest paid actor in hollywood is $270 million and he still gets paychecks from his previous movies.
```

Comment: What "special characters of non-sentence" do you want to remove? Edit your question; instead of a full screen dump, make up a short example and also explain _what you want to get,_ not just what you incorrectly get now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would isolate non-sentences from sentences first using this regex:

```
(?<=\n|^)[\S]*\s*?[\S]*\s*?[\S]*\s*?[\S]*\s*?[\S]*\s*?[\S]*(?=\n|$)
```

Then, apply the removal of the `spacial character`from non-sentences with a simple replace function.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/phrtfF/1